# Java - Basic use of arrays

Tags: java

This is a basic question but I do need some help.

Given two arrays of ints, a and b, return true if they have the same first element or they have the same last element. Both arrays will be length 1 or more.

> commonEnd({1, 2, 3}, {7, 3}) → true
>
> commonEnd({1, 2, 3}, {7, 3, 2}) → false
>
> commonEnd({1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}) → true

I have the following code but it wont compile:

```
public boolean commonEnd(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if(a[0] == b[0] || a[a.length-1] ==b[b.length-1])
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Please always include compiler error messages when code does not compile.

Comment: *"it is simple basic question but could u help me?"* I hope in your next question you can put an upper-case letter for the start of each sentence, and spell words like 'you' properly.  Till then..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Why not just...edit the question instead of nitpicking?

Comment: @Makoto  I edit many.  It is always a judgment call.  This one did not make the cut.

Comment: @AndrewThompson:  Well, I can't argue with that...

Comment: I made it work and i will be careful for those terms : ) Thanks guys

Comment: If one of the answers got it to work for you, please mark that answer as accepted. (Click on the check mark to the left of the answer.)

Answer (score 4):

- You have  missing right paren for the if.
- You need to return something (false) in the "else" part.

You should have gotten a compiler error to tell you this.

Personally, I'd get rid of the `if` altogether and do

```
return  a[0] == b[0] || a[a.length-1] ==b[b.length-1];
```

(but this may be considered hard to read)

Comment: I see nothing hard to read about this.  Solid answer here. :)

Answer (score 0):

you had no return type if, if is untrue

```
  public boolean commonEnd(int[] a, int[] b) {
  if(a[0] == b[0] || a[a.length-1] ==b[b.length-1])
      return true;
  return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean commonEnd(int[] a, int[] b) {
  if((a[0] == b[0]) || (a[a.length-1] ==b[b.length-1]))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

You have missed the return statement(if the if statement no true), that's why it didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
public boolean commonEnd(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int length1=a.length;
  int length2=b.length;
  if(a[0]==b[0]||a[length1-1]==b[length2-1]){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Expects return Statements for the function

```
public boolean commonEnd(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if(a[0] == b[0] || a[a.length-1] ==b[b.length-1]) //Missed `)`
          {
          return true;
          }
        return false;
     }
```

Comment: Actually the extra brace has occurred from workout for the probs sorry, updated the answer ...@SeanF